# Ph.D. enrollment from May to September

Tags: phd

Universities from which region in the world receive and process Ph.D. applications from May to September?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There're two basic kinds of PhD programs I'm familiar with. The first kind has a regular intake, sometimes divided into spring intake and fall intake. You join with a cohort of other students, take courses together, etc. This is presumably what you're thinking of, since you refer to intake months.

The other kind is join whenever you want, as long as there's a position for you. There's no official start date aside from the one you agree with your supervisor.

My understanding is that most universities in Europe and Australia/New Zealand follow the latter model.

Comment: We also hire phds whenever the job is open in the Netherlands.